# display the text with clicking on check box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write the two names with check boxes and want to show the text in console.log with checking the check boxes in java script.
i have tried this
but its not working

```html
<p>Pakistan <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" onclick="myFunction()"></p>
<p>India <input type="checkbox1" id="mycheck" onclick="myFunction"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("mycheck")
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      console.log("Pakistan")
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. change onclick="myFunction()" to onclick="myFunction(this)" 2. avoid duplicated ID 3. function myFunction(){ will be function myFunction(ele){ so you can use ele instead of checkbox

Comment: Input Type and all predefined In html. It should be 
 heckbox not checkbox1.

Answer (score 0):

your checkbox.check has a capital b whereas your declaration has lowercase

```html
  <p>Pakistan  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" onclick="myFunction()"></p>
  <p>India  <input type="checkbox1" id="mycheck" onclick="myFunction"></p>
      <script>
  function myFunction(){
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("mycheck")
  if (checkbox.checked == true){
    console.log("Pakistan")
  }
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be adding `this` to your onclick function, which will reference the checkbox for clicked element. You can then check if the checkbox is checked and print out the text of the parent element to get the "checkbox name"

Also make sure that you have `type = "checkbox"` not `checkbox1`, that is not a correct type. You also want to avoid duplicate ids, change `id="mycheck"` to a class or name them differently.

working snippet:

```html
<p>Pakistan <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck1" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
<p>India <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck2" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction(box) {
    if (box.checked == true) {
      console.log(box.parentElement.textContent)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but if i have to display a different text while clicking on 1st one i would like to display a differnt message on  different on the second checkbox

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand your question. Could you please rephrase? If you want to display a different text you can give the checkboxes a value attribute like so: `<p>India <input type="checkbox" id="mycheck2" value = "myValue" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>` and then reference the value like `box.value`. Otherwise I have no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, IDs are unique, so pass `this` into the function and check if it's checked - then `console.log` the text inside the parent:

```js
function myFunction(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    console.log(checkbox.parentNode.textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Pakistan <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
<p>India <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(chbx) {
    if(chbx.checked == true) {
        console.log(chbx.parentElement.textContent);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Pakistan <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
<p>India <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction(this)"></p>
```